# AForge.NET -> AVIWriter Adding Images as Frames

Tags: c#, image, video, photo, video-encoding

I want to make a video from images, and each image should stay for one second. 
The AVIWriter has 25 frames rate, so i have to add one image 25 times to make it stay for one second.

I tried changing the frame-rate, but it is not working.

Can anyone suggest a workaround?

The following is the code for writing frames into video:

```
    private void writeVideo()
    {
        // instantiate AVI writer, use WMV3 codec
        AVIWriter writer = new AVIWriter("wmv3");
        // create new AVI file and open it
        writer.Open(fileName, 320, 240);
        // create frame image
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(320, 240);
        var cubit = new AForge.Imaging.Filters.ResizeBilinear(320, 240);
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(imagesFolder);
        writer.FrameRate = 25;
        int index = 0;
        int failed = 0;
        foreach (var item in files)
        {
            index++;
            try
            {
                image = Image.FromFile(item) as Bitmap;
                //image = cubit.Apply(image);

                for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
                {
                    writer.AddFrame(image); 
                }   
            }
            catch
            {
                failed++;
            }
            this.Text = index + " of " + files.Length + ". Failed: " + failed;
        }
        writer.Close();
    }
```

Comment: what do you get when you add the same frame 25 times as you outlined?

Comment: AVI as container format is both okay for 1 fps frame rate, and for empty/missing frames. If you could find a way to timestamp your frames (such as frame #0, then frame #25) and push it through this library, the AVI API would automatically add missing frames as empty frames and resulting file would play back at 1 fps.

Comment: @box86rowh  when i add the same frame 25 times and the rate is 20 frames, then the frame stays for one second. when i reduced the frame rate to 20 and added 20 frames, then each frame stayed for less than one second.

Comment: @Inuyasha I posted related code for video frames adding....

Answer (score 2):

Hello I had the same problem and saw this topic read it all and no comment for 
http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/bc8345f8-8e09-c1a4-4834-8330e5e85605.htm
There is a note like that "The property should be set befor opening new file to take effect."

Answer (score 1):

The solution of Hakan is working, if you use this code:

```
AVIWriter videoWriter;
videoWriter = new AVIWriter("wmv3");
videoWriter.FrameRate = 1;
videoWriter.Open("test.avi", 320, 240);
videoWriter.AddFrame(bitmap1);
videoWriter.AddFrame(bitmap2);
videoWriter.AddFrame(bitmap3);
videoWriter.Close();
```

There is well one bitmap displayed per second.
(just for giving a directly working piece of code).

Answer (score 0):

The default frame rate for `AVIWriter` is 25. As you have no option to specify dropped or otherwise skipped frames, why wouldn't you set [`AVIWriter::FrameRate`](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/bc8345f8-8e09-c1a4-4834-8330e5e85605.htm) property to 1 before you start populating your writer with frames?

Comment: I have already tried writer.FrameRate = 1; but still its not working. The default is 25 and according to my 'bad' experience, it can't be updated.

Comment: The underlying AVI writer works in the following way: you not only provide new frame, but it is also timestamped. If you push frames #0, #1, #2 and then #9, the AVI writer layer will take this into account and takes care of skipper frames #3 through #8. So it seems that it's AForge.NET library limitation, as it ignores frame times. Perhaps you would want to look into AForge.NET code and update it to resolve the problem.